# "Uncaught (in promise): null" when lifting up the value of reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify, react-google-recaptcha

I'm trying to lift up the value of the reCAPTCHA (with [react-google-recaptcha](https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha)) once the user clicks it. I can easily get the value but I can't send it to the parent component. It throws:

> Uncaught (in promise): null

```
const RecaptchaInput = ({ name, isValid, errorMessage, onChange }) => {
  const recaptchaReference = useRef(null);

  const handleChange = () => {
    let recaptchaValue = recaptchaReference.current.getValue(); 
    console.log('recaptchaValue',recaptchaValue) //prompts the value

    onChange({ value: recaptchaValue, name: `recaptcha` });
  };

  return <div>
    <label htmlFor={name}>
      <Recaptcha sitekey={process.env.GATSBY_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY}
                 ref={recaptchaReference}
                 onChange={handleChange} />
    </label>
    {!isValid && <small>{errorMessage}</small>}
  </div>;
};
```

The value is properly prompted in the console but I can't send it `onChange` function. Neither a dummy object like `{value: 'hello', name: 'recaptcha'}`.

My `onChange` function destructures the arguments into `name` and `value`, that's why I lift up an object like this.

As far as I read it seems to be related to the callback of Google's Recaptcha but I can't figure out how to bypass it in Gatsby's/React application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trial and error, I fixed it by making an `async` promise-based value fetching. For everyone that may be stuck in the similar issues:

```
const RecaptchaInput = ({ name, isValid, errorMessage, onChange }) => {
  const recaptchaReference = useRef(null);

  const handleChange = async () => {
    let recaptchaValue = recaptchaReference.current.getValue(); 
    console.log('recaptchaValue',recaptchaValue) //prompts the value

    onChange({ value: recaptchaValue, name: `recaptcha` });
  };

  return <div>
    <label htmlFor={name}>
      <Recaptcha sitekey={process.env.GATSBY_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY}
                 ref={recaptchaReference}
                 onChange={handleChange} />
    </label>
    {!isValid && <small>{errorMessage}</small>}
  </div>;
};
```